# Should dimensional reduction be followed by a revision of the DOF in your model to avoid overfitting?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, overfitting

I am doing some research on classification and feature reduction using PCA and FA and after extracting the reduced scores from my original basis of dimension *n* (number of features) to a new d dimensional basis I am in the following situation:

> I spent quite some time doing hyper parameter optimisation over the original dataset to get a k-fold cross validated error around 17%
>
> After dimensionality reduction I repeat the process and results only experience a slight improvement. I am applying the same level of complexity (understood as degrees of freedom) in my model.

My question: 
Is there a theoretical reason to believe that dimensional reduction should be followed by model complexity reduction to avoid over fitting or can I trust regularisation with my reduced scores?

I know all cases are a different world but I am looking for advice coming from practical experience.

Thanks a lot for your time!